# Which fixes from mathtools were merged to the AMS packages already?

Tags: amsmath, mathtools, bugs

[mathtools](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) aims to fix bugs and problems with the AMS package set.

Quote from the AMS site http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex:

> In 2016, LuaTeX version 1 was released, and attempts to use amsmath with LuaLaTeX would fail. To address this problem most effectively, responsibility for maintenance of amsmath was transferred to the LaTeX Project, and the authoritative version of amsmath is now on CTAN and in TeX Live.

Which fix has made it into the AMS package already?

Can the LaTeX Project merge the fixes to amsmath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is really two questions. The original adjustments for luatex were done first in `amsmath` then communicated to the `mathtools` maintainers to incorporate there, similarly the fix to not need `\!` before `aligned`.

`mathtools` has some extensions and fixes to `amsmath` and there is a mid to long term aim to incorporate some of them back but mostly that's not done yet. As always the main issues are around document compatibility rather than difficulty in actually making the change.

You can see all the changes made since we picked up `amsmath` here

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commits/master/required/amsmath

Or a more curated top level description of the changes here

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/required/amsmath/changes.txt

Comment: Does this mean, it makes no sense to load mathtools in luatex+amsmath, because the fixes were made there first?

Comment: @JonasStein no it means that `mathtools` works at all in luatex as the immediate fixes required when luatex changed the behaviour of `\mathchardef` are incorporated. But as I note above the other unrelated extensions that mathtools adds over `amsmath` are still just in `mathtools`. Basically it means that they are in sync whoever the packages claim to be maintained by:  any changes made to `amsmath` will either not break `mathtools` or we will arrange that compatible update to `mathtools` happens at the same time.